# when will the number/nodes for the reducers be allocated in the mapreduce job execution?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

When reading about MapReduce, I read the below interesting lines:

> "*But how do the Reducer’s know which nodes to query to get their
>   partitions? This happens through the Application Master. As each
>   Mapper instance completes, it notifies the Application Master about
>   the partitions it produced during its run. **Each Reducer**
>   periodically queries the Application Master for Mapper hosts until it
>   has received a final list of nodes hosting its partitions.*"

I have a doubt here. When they say **Each Reducer** what does it mean exactly? Will the reducers be allocated before the starting of the map phase and also how are the reducer nodes chosen?

Answer (score 0):

Reducers can start before the maps are done with the processing of the data. Once they start they can pull the data from the mapper machines, but they will start the processing only after all the mappers are done processing of the data.

**mapred.reduce.slowstart.completed.maps** is the property to configure this behaviour. More information on the property [here](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html).

Comment: Thanks for the details Praveen..!! Will the reducers nodes be chosen based on the availability of task tracker in it? is there any possibility for a node to run the map as well the reduce task for a single job ?

Comment: The mappers are run based on the data locality, there are no constraints on where the reducers are run. Reducers are run based on the availability of the slots. The mapper and the reducer might/might not run the same machine. We don't have any control over it.